# Segregate Alphanumeric Characters from a String of Mixed Characters Inside an Excel Cell using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, alphanumeric, custom-functions-excel

I segregate numeric characters from a string of mixed characters inside a cell.

```vb
Function xxx(str As String) As String
Dim strarr() As String
str = Replace(str, ".", " ")
strarr = Split(str)
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(strarr)
    If strarr(i) Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then
        numfromstring = numfromstring & "," & strarr(i)
    End If
Next i

numfromstring = Mid(numfromstring, 2)
End Function
```

How can I do the same for alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 0):

### Get Alpha-Numeric UDF

```vb
Function GetAlphaNumeric( _
    ByVal Str As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As String
    
    Dim n As Long, Char As String, rStr As String
    
    For n = 1 To Len(Str)
        Char = Mid(Str, n, 1)
        If Char Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then rStr = rStr & Delimiter & Char
    Next n
    
    If Len(rStr) > 0 Then GetAlphaNumeric = Mid(rStr, 1 + Len(Delimiter))
    
End Function
```

Comment: Hi... I need the result to be shown like... Consider this is the input data "xxx
e223dbf2 ejgb4545g3 ejgbekhg 357357" -  e223dbf2, ejgb4545g3 (This should be the result, as there only 2 alphanumeric words in that array of strings or words). Please advise

Comment: Function xxx(str As String) As String
Dim strarr() As String
str = Replace(str, ".", " ")
strarr = Split(str)
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(strarr)
'If IsNumeric(strarr(i)) Then
 If strarr(i) Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then

    numfromstring = numfromstring & "," & strarr(i)
End If
Next i

numfromstring = Mid(numfromstring, 2)
End Function.......... This is not giving me the result. Please advise the way that we can get the accurate result in here, to list only alphanumeric characters in here. I have edited the same code in the main question itself for clear view.